# Is it possible for satellite communication to have less latency than cable and optic fiber?

Tags: telecommunications

I would expect satellite internet to have large latency. Apart from Starlink this holds for most of the rest. It seems you could argue that information travels a larger distance with respect to fiber or cable, and hence it is slower. I would expect that latency in fiber or cable networks also depends in the number of hops that information passes by.

As far as I understand it, most information, after leaving the home router, never travel by air again.  Even inter-continental information that moves through the internet travels by underwater cable and it seems that just doing it by air would finally be slower.

For modern mobile data and cable communications (I mean DSL here,) the latency varies from 10-100ms, whereas fiber I'd say is more between 1-10ms.

[Related article](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16438/speed-of-light-in-copper-vs-fiber-why-is-fiber-better)

Starlink expects 1-10ms. Is this possible for satellite communications?

Comment: Are you asking about geo-stationary satellite links (36,000 km, from memory) or low-Earth orbit?

Comment: The orbital parameters mean everything. Also, are you taking into consideration that light travels ~30% slower in a fiber optic medium than does an RF signal in free space, even given atmospheric effects.

Comment: There's more to it than just delays through repeaters: through air and vacuum, the signal will travel at close to the speed of light; through fibre or copper it's more like 0.6–0.7 times the speed of light.

Comment: There was an article in IEEE spectrum (June 2018) that discussed a similar scenario.  This one involved "latency arbitrage", which is taking advantage of time difference in financial market trading between one place and another to generate a profit.  A firm called Spread Networks laid a special fiber optic cable between Chicago & New York that reduced the round trip time to 14.5 ms.  Shortly after that was completed another firm built a special microwave link between those same two cities, which provided shorter latency than the FO link.

Comment: The IEEE Spectrum article (2018) concluded by saying that low-orbit satellites not are not able to provide such fast communications [as earth based systems].  What a difference 4 years make!

Comment: fiber supports far more bandwith then satellite, while the latancy is faster, information of larger sizes travel slower

Comment: Light (and radio) goes 300km in 1ms. Starlink, like other systems, orbits around 600km, so you have an absolute minimum of 4ms to get the signal there and back. I bet most of the delay in previous systems was more to do with error correction, coding, and contention.

Comment: @SteveSh https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16438/speed-of-light-in-copper-vs-fiber-why-is-fiber-better this is interesting. I think the difference you cite makes absolutely no sense. 70% of the speed of light is still the same order of magnitude. You are not saying 1/1000 th

Comment: @Transistor why would they put them at 36Mm ? I don't know. I mean the ones that would be usable

Comment: @AndrewMorton as I cited https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16438/speed-of-light-in-copper-vs-fiber-why-is-fiber-better. that `%` isn't relevant at all. It is still the same order of magnitude. How much difference would you experience in 0.7c or 0.9c ?

Comment: @cubesareneat i think you''re a few years out of date. I mean, they are selling 1GB/s bandwidth.

Comment: OP's opening sentence was "I would expect satellite internet to have large latency".  Given the faster speed of RF in air/vacuum vs a FO signal, and the fact that the RF/satellite  link distance between points on the ground (for satellites in LEO, where the Starlink satellites are) is not that much difference than a FO link (that has to follow the earth's circumference), I would not expect the latencies to be that much different.

Comment: @mah Nah 1GB/s is wild but how many people can they serve in an area maintaing that bandwith for everyone? the radio band spectum has finite bandwith. with multiple fiber cables the bandwith can be far denser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a more concrete example.  Assume we want to send information between two points on the earth's surface, call them A & B. One way to do that would be through a FO link that follows the earth's surface.  Another way would be to use a single satellite (blue box) in low earth orbit (LEO).  See the cartoon below.

[image]

I placed the satellite at an altitude of 310 miles.  At that altitude, the distance to the horizon, where the two ground stations are located, is 1,596 miles.  So the total path length between the two ground stations, using the satellite, is twice that, or ~3,200 miles.

The path the FO link would take is along the surface of the earth. The distance from A to B along the surface is ~3,100 miles.

So given the the speed of the data (light) through the FO link is ~30% slower than that using the RF link, we can compute the delays for the two paths.

For the satellite path, the delay is 17 ms.  For the FO earth's surface path, the delay is 23 ms.

Note that this analysis says nothing about equipment delays, but just looks at the propagation path delay for this simple scenario.

Obviously, the conclusion changes as the altitude of the satellite increases.  It also changes depending on the distance between the two ground stations.  In the corner case where A & B are right next to each other, the FO link delay would be zero, while the satellite path delay would be 3.3 ms, in this example.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to calculate the upper bound on distance, with back-of-envelope accuracy.

- 1 light-second is 300,000 km
- Therefore 1ms = 300 km and 10ms = 3,000 km.

Allowing for up- and down distances, you need to halve the altitude. And assuming momentarily you could reduce the additional delays to negligible:

- a satellite with 1ms latency has a *maximum* altitude of 150 km
- with 10ms it is 1,500 km

The international space station is one of the lower orbiting satellites ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit)), and is at approx 400 km; Starlink and similar have a number of altitudes ranging from about 350 km to 1200 km. ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink))

We see ethernet switch latencies around 100 us ([ref](https://www.fiberopticshare.com/network-latency-in-ethernet-switches.html)), so we know that the networking equipment can be made with low delays.

So, yes, this is plausible.

Comment: But there's a lot more to the latency from point A to point B on the earth's surface than just switch latency.  It's not a fair comparison to compare the latency of a network switch by itself, (ignoring the distance between the end points) to the latency of the path to the satellite.

Comment: I don't disagree with you @SteveSh, but it's just a "plausibility back-of-envelope sense-check" which is intended to give a "under some conditions might be possible" answer.  If you're trying to work it out for real there are a *lot* of things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Air is not slower. The speed of propagation of a signal in air is greater than 99% of the speed of light, while the speed of propagation of a signal in coaxial cable or optical fiber is generally between 60% and 85% of the speed of light.

Going up and down to satellites does incur an ionospheric delay (which depends on space weather, the signal frequency, and how far the satellite is above the horizon), but that's generally something like a microsecond — significant for something like GPS, but small compared to the total time of flight.

So while a satellite link will *usually* have a higher latency due to a longer path length, it doesn't have to be that way. It's entirely possible for the numbers to work out in satellite's favor, if the satellite is lower than GEO, and/or the terrestrial link isn't the perfect shortest geodesic path.

Comment: Do you know what 60% means? It means 60*3*10**8/100. Mate, that is basically the same speed. The fact that you are using 60% and 70% confuses you. The change in time will be in the 7th decimal.

Comment: @MahNeh Yes, I know what 60% means. Pointless gymnastics aside, the difference is in the *first* digit, just as it is when multiplying *any* number (big or small) by .6, and is not "basically the same speed".

Comment: Fine. Thanks for the answer and patience